# What to do when another user reverts my edits?

Tags: discussion, edits

On May 15 I flagged [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23682090/how-can-a-sub-class-access-not-static-members-of-an-abstract-class) for a moderator because my edits kept being reversed for what I deem a bad reason: apparently my change of "syso" to "System.out.println" was considered an invalid code change.

Here's why I believe my edit was perfectly fine:

- `syso` is a shortcut for `System.out.println` in Eclipse
- The language used is Java
- My edit doesn't change any other code except indentation
- My edit cleaned up what else was wrong with the post

After said user reverted my changes back twice I flagged it for a moderator so it wouldn't end up as a rollback war and accompanied it with a message stating

> My changes are unreasonably being reverted because changing "syso" to "system.out.println" is considered a (radical) code change. It's a known shortcut to type it in Eclipse and my edit addresses every issue in the post otherwise.

Yesterday (over a month later) it got declined as

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

I did not talk about a technical inaccuracy nor was it referring to an answer.

What to do when another user reverts my edits?

Comment: If you had not made the mistake of writing `system` instead of `System`, this would be a even more troublesome... but rolling back without actually seeing that all is missing is a capital letter isn't better.

Comment: I think that changing working code in other way than reformatting is wrong. Perhaps not here, but in general one can imagine that in some cases writing `syso` instead of `System.out.println` could be the root of the problem. Or at least some important information hidden in the question.

Comment: @BartoszKP talking about *just reformatting* : i saw a question on code golf where a program behaved differently if an empty new-line was inserted on code source. That means, in extreme cases of course, *just reformatting* can also cause/hide the problem :P -of course i strongly agree that changing `syso` to `System.out.println` is wrong because itself can be the root of the problem

Comment: What I often do in this case is **EDIT IN A 'NOTE'**.  So, click edit, and down the bottom make three dashes, and then type something like "Note - it's likely syso here is an Eclipse 4.0 shortcut for fsock" or whatever.  "Notes" in questions (and indeed answers) are very useful to everyone. They're sort of one step up from adding a comment.  Example, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/402/iphone-app-in-landscape-mode-2008-systems  (note the note I edited in)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You did the right thing by flagging. The post was later fixed to include your changes. The flag was declined for such a wildly wrong reason that I can only assume that it was a mis-click, which is rare, but it does happen.  Sorry about the confusion it caused.

Comment: I'm not really sure how changing the code is a good thing. It being a shortcut is, as far as I know, irrelevant. The code the OP is using was including `syso` and I believe that should be in the question? There is no real reason to change it, but maybe in a wrong version of eclipse the shortcut doesn't work? I'm not saying this is the case, but as there is no real downside to just leave it as it is, why take the chance?

Comment: @Nanne 'syso' is an Eclipse keyboard macro that expands to "System.out.println". It's not Java code. The question is about a completely different Java feature, not the Eclipse macro. This is pretty obvious from both the question and the answer, so there's no risk in fixing it.

Answer (score 13):

Just because `syso` is a shortcut in Eclipse does not make it any less of a legal identifier.

You should have made the formatting changes, but left a comment concerning `syso`, because only the OP knows whether he meant the Eclipse shortcut or uses that as the actual name of something in his code (it would be a method, from the usage).

Comment: I agree that code changes should be made with caution but let's be honest: the chances that `syso("ID : " + id);` does not refer to printing something to the command line are extraordinarily small. I believe common sense should prevail in such situations and accept that such a very likely change should be possible.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel Unfortunately, "common sense" is not that common. If we allow such changes, then we would also allow refactorings that seem "obvious" to some people but are not necessarily obvious in general.

Comment: I know Java, but I've never used Eclipse, and I've never seen anyone use `syso` here before, so the post makes much more sense to me thanks to Jeroen's change.  And it's possible the OP didn't realize it wasn't a universal idiom.  I think it was a good change (aside from the capitalization error), but he should have added a comment, too.

Comment: @SList: which is why there is a "Skip" button.

Comment: @SList Which is why you can filter by tag ;-)

Comment: `Just because syso is a shortcut in Eclipse does not make it any less of a legal identifier.` _If_ you happen to be writing in Eclipse. A Java question should not care about that. It should be about Java.

Comment: @ninjalj I was unaware of the existence of this shortcut until I read this discussion.  If I had reviewed the change, how should I have known that it referred to some knowledge that I didn't have, rather than being a rather random code change (although admittedly one that eliminated compiler errors that weren't discussed in the question)?  In other words, how would I have known that I should skip it rather than decline it?

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Umm, my point is that it's legal in Java code (if you also define it).  It fits the Java grammar for an identifier.

Comment: @Jules: good point. The editor should have pointed that out in the edit description, which he didn't, leaving the rather unhelpful: _"deleted 9 characters in body"_.

Answer (score 12):

Code changes **in a question** are risky.  I have seen any number of cases where someone's honest attempt to make the questioner's code more readable removed the bug they were asking about.

That doesn't mean you shouldn't make them!  The site only survives because we fix up the noobs' egregious lack of indentation, after all.  But it does mean you should do them only with extreme care, erring on the side of leaving things the way they were originally, and if someone reverts a change, discuss it with them in the comments *before* you put it in again.

(In **answers**, more aggressive editing is usually safe; but I would still adhere to the "if someone reverts your change, discuss it with them before putting it in again" policy out of basic courtesy.)

Comment: Jup, ff bugs are that easy to remove, better cv the whole question.

Comment: @hakre It's not that simple.  A valid question about subtleties of C lexical syntax could easily depend on exactly where the spaces were, for instance.  For another, there is a lot of C out there which is indented, shall we say, *oddly*.  "I inherited this white-elephant codebase, it works as is but when I ran it through `indent` to make my eyes stop bleeding it broke, here's an example function, wtf" would also be an on-topic question.

Comment: @hakre (Things may well be different in your tags, I can only speak about mine.)

Comment: @Zack: You'd still indent that to make it appear as code (but not change whitespace within the code)

Comment: Yeah, we most likely see that from a different viewpoint. I do much PHP an in PHP for example, the whitespace is not that sharp in making a difference like let's say in bash.